# SELECT COUNT query on indexed column

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a simple table storing words for different ids.

```
CREATE TABLE words (
    id INTEGER,
    word TEXT,
);
CREATE INDEX ON words USING hash (id);
CREATE INDEX ON words USING hash (word);
```

Now I simply want to count the number of times a given word appears. My actual query is a bit different and involves other filters.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM "words"
                    WHERE word = 'car'
```

My table has a billion of rows but the answer for this specific query is about 45k.
I hoped that the index on the words would make the query super fast but it still takes a 1 min 20 to be executed, which looks dereasonable. As a comparison, `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM "words"` takes 1 min 57.

Here is the output of EXPLAIN:

```
Aggregate  (cost=48667.00..48667.01 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on words  (cost=398.12..48634.05 rows=13177 width=0)
        Recheck Cond: (word = 'car'::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on words_word_idx  (cost=0.00..394.83 rows=13177 width=0)
              Index Cond: (word = 'car'::text)
```

I don't understand why there is a need to recheck the condition and why this query is not efficient.

Comment: Count is always bad in a sense of performace, as you have more and more rows it will get worse, the qiestion is how often do you need the count. if often make a new table with wort, count run a INSERT New table SELECT word, count(*) FROM worrds Group by word and incease the count be trigger, that will cost somewhat when unserting and updating, but will save you lots of tome later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hash indexes don't store the indexed value in the index, just its 32-bit hash and the ctid (pointer to the table row).  That means they can't resolve hash collisions on their own, so it has to go to the table to obtain the value and then recheck it.  This can involve a lot or extra IO compared to a btree index, which do store the value and can support index only scans.

Comment: I added a btree index and now the same query executes in 60 ms!

Answer (score 1):

You could use B-Tree index whenever an indexed column is involved in a comparison using one of these operators:

```
<   <=   =   >=   >
```

I assume you are using `=` for counting how many words are there. So, B-Tree index satisfy your requirements.

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES-BTREE

Comment: A hash-based index should work for `=` comparisons. Why would a B-Tree work better for my use case?

Comment: B-Tree index is suitable for wide range of values while hash index must be whole keys to search for a row. (With a B-tree index, any leftmost prefix of the key can be used to find rows.)